# How can I send and receive messages async on JSON Node JS

Tags: node.js, async-await, socket.io

I need help with async function on my receive and send node js server.

I am trying to send and receive text messages from node js to and fro IOS app. I am able to do both individually but it do not work when i combine them together.

I have tried both async/await and settimeout() on both send and receive function but it did not work. My receiving msg will not receive till I send a msg out from node js and it will receive the msg in one go into my node js console and I will not be able to send anymore msg to IOS from node js console.

And after sending an output msg from node js, I can receive msg from IOS smoothly and timely. But the send msg function will not be able to work.

The code below is my node js code and able to run but not completed. The flow of my code is it will wait for user to enter an input before receiving any input msg and it will be able to keep constantly receiving msg from sender after passing by the send function. The sending function is the obstacle blocking the receiving function from receiving msg.

Thank you for your time.

```
var express = require('express');
const { receiveMessageOnPort } = require('worker_threads');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

connections = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 2229);
console.log('Server is running...');

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  connections.push(socket); // count number of connections
  console.log('Connect: %s sockets are connected', connections.length);
  console.log('Time out');
  console.log('Before loop');

  io.sockets.emit('iOS Client Port', { msg: 'Hi from server' }); // send to iOS

  receive();
  setTimeout(() => {
    send();
  }, 100);

  function send() {
    const prompt = require('prompt-sync')({});
    let msg = prompt('Enter: ');
    socket.emit('iOS Client Port', { msg });
  }

  function receive() {
    socket.on('NodeJS Server Port', function (data) {
      console.log(data); // msg from iOS, data is the file sent from iOS
    });
  }
});
```